# How to connect to Cisco W3550 with FreeBSD

Tags: serial, bsd

There is a pfsense 2.0.1 (FreeBSD) and the command `cu` for access to the serial console, there is a Cisco W3550 attached but I can't get a connection.

I try following Command:

```
cu /dev/cuau0 -speed 9600
```

or

```
cu -ehot /dev/cuau0 -speed 9600
```

But I can't get a connection, there still came following output.

```
usage: cu [-ehot] [-a acu] [-l line] [-s speed | -speed] [phone-number]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On following link i found my answer: http://onlamp.com/bsd/2001/10/11/FreeBSD_Basics.html

With this command i can connect to cisco router on serial console under pfsense (FreeBSD)

```
cu -l /dev/cuau0 -s 9600
```